# PDFRenderer creates images of greater size than the PDF itself

Tags: java, pdf, graphics, jpeg, pdfbox

I have a sample of scanned PDFs that I need to edit and re-export. I use PDFBox to render the PDF into a series of images (one image per page), I perform some OpenCV calculations on the rasterized jpegs and then I intend to insert them back into a new pdf file.

Example: PDF is 423kb, Page 1 is 313kb, Page 2 is 287kb, Page 3 is 319kb, Page 4 is 485kb, and Page 5 is 470kb.

Problem is that the output images are greater in size than the PDF itself. This results in my OCR efforts taking much longer than is acceptable (5 minutes vs 30 seconds per document). The only way to keep the jpegs from inflating in size is to leave them with a default DPI of 72. This produces poor quality images that cannot be used.

Why is this happening? I should be able to get back images that have a size less than or equal to the PDF in question (without sacrificing quality). I'm not doing anything weird to the images, just removing watermarks.

Here's some code illustrating how I'm extracting the jpegs from the PDF.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
BufferedImage[] pageArray = new BufferedImage[document.getNumberOfPages()];
int pageCounter = 0;
for(PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
    pageArray[pageCounter] = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 160);
    pageCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Instead of *rendering* the pages you should *extract* the existing bitmap from the pdf.

Comment: more details if you share the PDF.